# WindowBuilder Pro encoding situation

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

We recently moved a big Visual Editor project to Eclipse Juno (4.2) and WindowBuilder Pro and the transition went smoothly besides one little and weird encoding problem.

Heres how it looks on the design page of WB when I use some kind of accentuation (Im talking about Brazilian Portuguese here...):

[image: the normal labels]

and now how it ends up on the source code:

[image: and heres the bugged one]

It seems to be a problem with the WindowBuilder encoding itself or something like that, but on the eclipse preferences I could only find the workspace encoding wich is setup to the default:

[image: our default encoding]

Changing the encoding of the workspace to UTF-8 or ISO resolves the problem on the source, but messes with the designer...
Anyone know where can I fix this?

Comment: Same situation here... Did you find a solution?